# image size adjust (no IDs) by a single javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, size

How to adjust size of all images to 400*300 in a html file
keeping following conditions ?

1. with a single javascript located at the top
2. without any additional file like css
3. there are no Ids for images at present

In other words, I am finding a javascript (blahblah part) of a form

```
<script>
...
blahblah
...
</script>

<img src="image/01.jpg">
<img src="image/02.jpg">
...
<img src="image/99.jpg">
```

which will get the same effect as following

```
<img src="image/01.jpg" width=400 height=300>
<img src="image/02.jpg" width=400 height=300>
...
<img src="image/99.jpg" width=400 height=300>
```

Comment: Why do you need your script at the top?

Comment: I am just studying javascript.. I just want to know it is possible in easy way. Thank you.

Comment: Use [getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName). You will not need any IDs.

Comment: Your statement does not make any sense.

Comment: I think you should at least try to write code before asking us to do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach((img) => ([img.width, img.height] = [400, 300])), false);
```

Comment: I'm glad it worked out for your usecase. If it completely satisfy you, please accept the answer.